# When does a Users Score go from xxxx to x.xk and what happens at 1000k

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, user-interface

Really simple, just curious.

When does a Users Score go from nnnn to n.nk

And what happens @ 1000k

Comment: At 10k: https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=185&tab=reputation&filter=all. It's kind of obvious given there are 4 digit rep numbers, makes no sense to switch at e.g. 8.5k.

Comment: Yeh seems like it does. Thanks :)

Comment: @l4mpi A much more interesting question is how the system will handle it when Jon Skeet reaches 1000k :)

Comment: @ivarni hmmm yeh ill add that to the question ;)

Comment: @Matt If he keeps hitting the 200 rep cap a day we'll know in about 1300 days. I'll make a mental note to come back and post an answer.

Comment: @Matt Actually, about 1300 days is the latest point in time in which he'll reach 1M, it will probably happen sooner as he tends to gain more than that daily.

Comment: yeh + with bounties etc. But with the question getting into the negative i dont think a mod is going to come along and clarify what happens any time soon!

Comment: The fifth motorcyclist of the apocalypse manifests on earth and slaughters all the PHP developers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It'll show 9999, and then 10k. So, it switches at 10k.

As for 1 million rep, it'll show 1m. SE's number formatter already supports it:
[image: "1.8m awarded"]

---

And... Jon Skeet has reached 1 million! And this answer has been proven wrong:

[image: "1000k"]

Comment: I'll be sure to take a look at that when Jon Skeet inevitably gets there.

Comment: Well there we go!

Comment: @IronMan84 Take a look then.

Comment: As of writing this, Jon Skeet's score is displayed as **1000k**, [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261957/107625).

Comment: This Jon Skeet fellah has been known to break CSS formatting before. SO can't keep up with this. I say, ban him for life.

Comment: Honestly, I would have expected them to just remove the rep entirely for him. Jon Skeet needs no metrics

Comment: Thanks @Rotem! I appreciate that.

Comment: the code currently has 3 scales for reputation; the third is for >=100000, with a scale of "k" and divisor of 1000